# Entity Framework Dynamic Where Condition

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm new in WPF and Entity Framework. I've researched many related question but none of them solved my problem.

Is it possible to create below condition dynamically ?
I mean that I want to create a condition like ("Name="Carlo"") and use it in EF. I don't want to write ok.Name because condition columns will generated dynamically.

```
  using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext)
        {
            string test = db.MyTable.Where(ok => ok.Name == Carlo).Select(ok => ok.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            return test;            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/):

```
db.MyTable.Where("Name=='Carlo'").Select("ID").FirstOrDefault();
```

You can find details for this project here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: thanks for answer, I've tried your suggestion but it's giving below error.   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyTable>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You need to add the DLL to your project (by download it or by [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/)) and than `include System.Linq.Dynamic;`.